# Does adding a value to a floating point number and then subtracting that same value give the original number?

Tags: floating-point

Let's say I have a floating point number `a` and I add another floating point number `b` to it to get `c`. Then I subtract `b` from `c` to get `d`. Does IEEE floating point guarantee that `a == d`?

In other words, will the following always return true no matter the values of `a` and `b`?

```
c = a + b
d = c - b
return a == d
```

(Apologies if this question has been asked before, I'm not sure what this mathematical principal is called and so wasn't sure what to search for.)

Comment: Note that the original asks about subtracting `y` and then adding `y` rather than adding and then subtracting. However, floating-point arithmetic is symmetric with regard to size (except for some rounding with zero), so this question is equivalent with `-y` substituted for `y`.

Comment: @Eric Thanks much, I figured someone had already asked an equivalent question, just wasn't able to find one.

Comment: Oops, typo above, “size” should be “sign”.